# Artifactory for Peoplecode

Tags: artifactory, peoplesoft

I am new to peoplesoft area and would like to check if we can use Artifactory OR nexus repository server to store the peoplecode binary 
i can compile the code using App designer but once we compile the code, need to create the package and store it to artifsctory server.

does it seems logical OR totally wrong assumption/understanding 
please suggest

Regards

Answer (score 1):

On its own PeopleSoft does not have version control. It has change control, but that is something different.
However, there are third party solutions on the market that fill this gap: STAT and Phire, to name two.

What you could do, if you don't want another tool with a licence: export your projects to file and check these files into the repository. You can revert to an earlier version by importing the file in App Designer

Comment: thanks. another doubt is, can we use maven tool to build the people-code ? i assume that, peoplecode is also an object programming language so we can use maven to build/compile that ?

Comment: Every time you save the code in App Designer, the code is compiled. Both uncompiled and compiled code are stored in the underlying database. You can't use another tool to build

Comment: thanks. can you please suggest some devops benefit from the continuous integration and continuous delivery perspective. how we can achieve the CI for peoplesoft,peoplecode etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Decode Peoplecode project at https://sourceforge.net/projects/decodepcode/files/ to extract the peoplecode source code.  You can also use this java project to check the code into a git or subversion repository.